# Xamarin Forms Application build problem missing DLL

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been fighting this error and the suggestions of cleaning, rebuilding, deleting `obj/bin` files and restarting have not worked for me. Any suggestions appreciated!

```
The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin_Test_Project, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin_Test_Project.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Xamarin_Test_Project.Android
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean ***solution***.

Build one project at a time starting at the top - NOT rebuild solution - just one project at a time.

When done, try to ***F5*** Debug.

Full docs [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/the-resolvelibraryprojectimports-task-failed-unexpectedly)